# Indexing an Object's properties by its position

Tags: java, arrays

I have this object that contains arrays of different objects:

```
long [] arr_1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int [] arr_2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
double [] arr_3 = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0};
String [] arr_4 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
Grouping obj = new Grouping(arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, arr_4);
```

Then I have a class named Grouping which stores these 4 different arrays:

```
public class Grouping(){

    private long [] a;
    private int [] b;
    private double [] c;
    private String [] d;

    public Grouping(long [] a, int [] b, double [] c, String [] d){
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d;
    }
}
```

Now I want to send this into a for-loop and compare the values inside of the array.

NOTE: "compare(obj[j] to obj[k]) does NOT work and that is the line I need help with.

```
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
             compare(obj[j] to obj[k]);
         }
     }
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This can't be done as you've presented it--consider storing each of your four arrays inside of another array or another data structure.

Comment: Exactly what are you comparing to what, and what do you want to happen depending on the comparison?

Comment: `obj` is **not** an array. So it you can't use `[]` notation.

Comment: I want to compare Object's j'th property to the Object's k'th property. What I truly want to do is use "assertEquals()" in order to test out multiple values.

Comment: @PM77-1 : I am very aware that I cannot use [] notation. That's the reason why I am asking this very question.

Comment: @qu4ntumcpa: how would I store four different data structures into an array?

Comment: When are two objects of type `Grouping` are considered equal?

Comment: What do you *want* to be at `obj[j]`? A group of `(long, int, double, String)`? If so, you're doing this wrong, and you should have an array of objects, each with its own `(long, int, double, String)`. A bunch of arrays that happen to have related data stored at the same index is about as weak a data structure as you can have, and you're using a language that was designed to encapsulate crap like that.

Comment: Why do you have a nested loop?

Comment: @DaveNewton:  At obj[index], I wish for it to return the array of whatever type the index holds. For example: obj[0] would return an array of long, obj[1] would return an array of integers, and obj[2] would return an array of doubles.

Comment: When you define a new class it's always a good idea to [override its `equals` method](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~kmammen/documents/java/howToOverrideEquals.html). In your case it seems to a necessity.

Comment: @Stevantti So write a `get` method that returns the right thing for the right index. But yuck.

Comment: @peeskillet: I wish to compare the 4 different arrays to each other and itself. Compare 0 to 0, compare 0 to 1, compare 0 to 2, compare 0 to 3, compare 1 to 0... you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.` notation if you don't have `get` methods

```
for (int j=0; j < obj.a.length ; j++){

    obj.compare(obj.a[j], obj.b[j]);

}
```

This is assuming `Grouping` has a `compare` method. I don't the context in which you're using the `compare` method.

I'm not even sure where this loop is located, whether it's in the `Grouping` class or after your instantiation of `Grouping`.

you can't just call a compare method where none exists. You need to something like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < obj.a.length; j++){

    if (obj.a[j] == obj.b[j]){
        // do something
    }

}
```

Comment: The for loops are placed in the main class. There are no compare method in Grouping. That line "obj.compare" was the line I don't know how to achieve and thus this question is asking for.

Comment: You can't just call a `compare` method where one doesn't exist. see my edit if you're trying to compare.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this comparison? What output are you expecting? Maybe there's a workaround

Comment: I believe you're missing a point here: you can't use such syntax since `obj` is **not** an array.

Comment: @PM77-1, I understand that. But If OP is trying to compare values in the array, he can do that. For example he can compare all the values as I have done and if all values are equal, he can have a boolean that represents the two arrays being equal. Other than that, you're right, I may be missing something about what OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a, b, c and d in another data structure.
If you use an ArrayList (or another List), for example, you can use the method get(int index) to get the wanted index.

Comment: You can't store different data types in an arraylist.

Comment: You can try an ArrayList of Object, and use casts when needed. But I'm not certainly if will help...